# DbExtensions - How to create WHERE clause with OR conditions?

Tags: ado.net, oledb, dbextensions

I'm trying to create `WHERE` clause with `OR` conditions using [DbExtensions](http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/).

I'm trying to generate SQL statement which looks like

```
SELECT ID, NAME
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ID = 100 OR NAME = 'TEST'
```

My C# code is

```
var sql = SQL.SELECT("ID, FIRSTNAME")
             .FROM("EMPLOYEE")
             .WHERE("ID = {0}", 10)
             .WHERE("NAME = {0}", "TEST");
```

How do I get the OR seperator using the above mentioned DbExtensions library?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a definition for logical OR operator [here](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/blob/aed17633800eaffff737c12910f8e2a4a6aa66c2/DbExtensions/SqlBuilder.cs)

```
  public SqlBuilder _OR<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string itemFormat, Func<T, object[]> parametersFactory) {
     return _ForEach(items, "({0})", itemFormat, " OR ", parametersFactory);
  }
```

And some code examples [here](https://github.com/maxtoroq/DbExtensions/blob/master/samples/CSharp/SqlBuilder.cs)

```
 public SqlBuilder Or() {

 int[][] parameters = { new[] { 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4} };

 return SQL
    .SELECT("p.ProductID, p.ProductName")
    .FROM("Products p")
    .WHERE()
    ._OR(parameters, "(p.CategoryID = {0} AND p.SupplierID = {1})", p => new object[] { p[0], p[1] })
    .ORDER_BY("p.ProductName, p.ProductID DESC");
 }
```

I think (by analogy with example) in your case code should be something like this (but I can't test it for sure):

```
var params = new string[] { "TEST" };

var sql = SQL.SELECT("ID, FIRSTNAME")
             .FROM("EMPLOYEE")
             .WHERE("ID = {0}", 10)
             ._OR(params, "NAME = {0}", p => new object[] { p })
```

Hope this helps :)

---

By the way... have you tried this way?

```
var sql = SQL.SELECT("ID, FIRSTNAME")
             .FROM("EMPLOYEE")
             .WHERE(string.Format("ID = {0} OR NAME = '{1}'", 10, "TEST"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler than you think:

```
var sql = SQL
   .SELECT("ID, FIRSTNAME")
   .FROM("EMPLOYEE")
   .WHERE("(ID = {0} OR NAME = {1})", 10, "TEST");
```

Comment: I need to add `OR` clause in a loop. One approach is to build the entier `WHERE` clause first and then use it as you mentioned above.  I was looking something more fluent syntax.  `var sql = SQL.SELECT("ID, FIRSTNAME")
             .FROM("EMPLOYEE")
             .WHERE("ID = {0}", 10)
             .WHERE_OR("NAME = {0}", "TEST");`

Comment: An .Append_OR would be great to have here, i have use for it as well

Answer (score 0):

One can use:

```
.AppendClause("OR", ",", "NAME = {0}",new object[]{"TEST"});
```